# How do I send a hex string with AWS CLI for IoT devices?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I'm trying to send a stream of data to an IoT device. The general data flow is:

- Send payload via AWS CLI or custom tool written by coworkers.
- Lambda function receives base64 encoded payload, converts to hex string, and forwards data to device.
- Device unescapes the data and then parses it to run a command.

The issue I'm running into is this: we would like to move away from using a very fragile custom tool since we're a small team and the devs who wrote it have moved on. The AWS CLI only accepts raw or base64 encodings for data, and my current input is a hex string like "C00020000000ff64". I am able to send data with the following commands in a powershell script:

```
$tmp="<SOME_HEX_STRING>"
$tmp -split '(.{2})' | %{ if ($_ -ne "") { $payload += [CHAR]([CONVERT]::toint16("$_",16)) }}
aws --region <SOME_AWS_REGION> iot-data publish --topic "<TOPIC_ID_HERE>" --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload "$payload"
```

However, the base64 parsing by the lambda function seems to barf at this approach and I get mangled data on the IoT device. I do not currently have debug access to our server to check the logs, but the actual parsing is done in node as a simple `Buffer.from(event.payload, 'base64')`, which is then parsed into an object containing a hex string. My impression is that the encoding method I'm using for input with the CLI is likely wrong (I strongly suspect that [CHAR] cast, to be honest), but I don't know enough in this situation to be able to identify where the problem is in my code, and Python (the code base for AWS CLI) is not my strong suit, so looking at their repo has only led to dead ends, moreso since there are no examples for using `aws iot-data publish`.

So my question is this:

Does anyone have a reliable method of converting a hex string to base64 or raw binary for input with AWS CLI?

Comment: Does `$payload` after running that PowerShell code look good to you? If you're attempting to convert `$tmp` to Base64 or raw bytes that's not the way you should approach the code.

Comment: Yeah, it's coming out exactly how I expect it to.

Comment: This is how `$payload` looks for me after running your PS Code: `À ÿd` using `C00020000000ff64` as `$tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

If the hex string is being passed to Python, I believe it is expecting a UTF8 Base64 Enconded string. Your current `$payload` is definitely not Base64.

This is how you can encode your payload:

```
$tmp = 'C00020000000ff64'

$payload = [convert]::ToBase64String(
    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($tmp)
)

python3 ./decode.py $payload # => Decoded from Python: b'C00020000000ff64'
```

- **decode.py**

```
import base64, sys

print(
    'Decoded from Python: {0}'.format(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
)
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response - today's AWS outage made testing your answer a bit tough. This definitely seems to work just fine for encoding to base64, but for some reason the AWS CLI is giving even worse mangling on the receiving side when I specify to read base64 with `aws --region <REGION> iot-data publish --topic "<TOPIC>" --payload "$payload"`. Granted, in my case I'm testing against `us-east-1`, so I can't discount issues there, at least not today.